# How to create a WordPress page that filters user input to questions and direct them accordingly to where they need to go

Tags: wordpress, filtering

I was wondering if there's a simple way to show users images and based on their choice they are shown more questions and finally sent to the correct page based on the answers. 
For example: If I show an iPhone image and a Samsung phone image the user would choose one; then a choice of models of either phone in images would be shown and so on till finally the user is sent to a certain URL based on their choices.

Answer (score 0):

Why not install InstantSearch+ for WordPress/WooCommerce. It's a live search that will filter your user's search and eventually get him to the right page.

Comment: That's a neat plugin, maybe I'll integrate that later on. I'm looking for a way to ask questions to the user by images and as the user chooses it dynamically shows more options.